# Finding the invariant factors of $G/G'$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm reading [*"Presentations of Groups,"*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=H004AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq="find+the+invariant+factors+of"+"the+following+seven+presentations"&source=bl&ots=QwlfcJEleP&sig=3OkbfBOV8tl3oRiKcnS4whzYcLw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHoZP64f_XAhWCKsAKHRTDAkUQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22find%20the%20invariant%20factors%20of%22%20%22the%20following%20seven%20presentations%22&f=false) by D. L. Johnson.

### Tl;dr:

> How do you find the invariant factors of $G/G'$ from a presentation of a group $G$?

### The Details:

In **Chapter 3** of the book *ibid.*, on Abelian groups, there are the following theorems.

> **Theorem 1:** The cyclic group of order $n\in\Bbb N$ has a presentation $\langle x\mid x^n\rangle$.
>
> **Theorem 2:** The Abelian group $$A=\Bbb Z_{d_1}\times\dots\times\Bbb Z_{d_r}\times\underbrace{\Bbb Z\times\dots\times\Bbb Z,}_{n-r\text{ times,}}\tag{1}$$ where $r, n$ and the $d_i$ are integers with $d_i\ge 2$ and $n\ge r$, has a presentation $$\langle X\mid P, C\rangle,$$ where 
>   $$\begin{align}
> X&=\{x_i\mid i\in \overline{1, n}\}, \\
> P&=\{x_i^{d_i}\mid i\in\overline{1,r}\}, \\
> C&=\{[x_i, x_j]\mid i, j\in \overline{1, n}, i<j\},
> \end{align}$$ where $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is the commutator of $a, b$.
>
> **Theorem 3:** Let $F$ be free on $X=\{x_i\mid i\in\overline{1, n}\}$ and let $R=\{[x_i, x_j]\mid 1\le i<j\le n\}$. Then:
>
> (i) $\overline{R}=F'$ (and I'm not sure what $\overline{R}$ is; please tell me in the comments),
>
> (ii) $F/F'=\langle X\mid R\rangle$,
>
> (iii) $F/F'$ is free Abelian of rank $n$, and
>
> (iv) $F/F'$ is isomorphic to the direct product of $n$ infinite cyclic groups.
>
> **Theorem 4:** Let $X$ be as above. If $\langle X\mid R\rangle$ is a presentation for a group $G$, then $\langle X\mid R, S\rangle$ is a presentation for $G/G'$, where $S=\{[x_i, x_j]\mid 1\le i<j\le n\}$.
>
> **Definition 1:** Suppose we have a presentation $$\langle x_1,\dots , x_n\mid r_1, \dots, r_m\rangle\tag{2}$$ for a group $G$, and let $a_{ij}\in\Bbb Z$ be the sum of the exponents with which the generator $x_i$ appears in the relator $r_j$. We call $A=(a_{ij})$ the *relation matrix* of the presentation.
>
> **Theorem 5:** Let $A$ be the relation matrix of a presentation $(2)$ of a group $G$ and let $h_i$ be the highest common factor of the $i$-rowed minors of $A$ (and $h_0=1$). If $h_{r+1}$ is the first of these to be zero, then $G/G'$ is isomorphic to the direct product of $r$ finite cyclic groups, of orders $\frac{h_i}{h_{i-1}}$ with $i\in\overline{1, r}$, and the free Abelian group of rank $n-r$.

### The Question(s):

*NB: It may seem like I'm asking multiple questions, but I'm really only asking one, viz., . . .*

> **Question 1:** Given the theorems above, how do I find the invariant factors of $G/G'$ from a given presentation of $G$?

*To avoid things being too broad and for concrete examples, the book asks us to . . .*

> Find the invariant factors of $G/G'$ when $G$ is given by the following seven presentations, respectively:
>
> 1. $\langle a, b, c,d,e\mid ab=c, bc=d, cd=e, de=a, ea=b\rangle$.
> 2. $\langle a,b,c,d,e,f\mid ab=c, bc=d, cd=e, de=f, ef=a, fa=b\rangle$.
> 3. $\langle x, y, z\mid (xyx)^2, x^3=y^3, (zxy)^4\rangle$.
> 4. $\langle x, y, z\mid (xy)^2, z^4, [x,z], [y, z]\rangle$.
> 5. $\langle x, y, z\mid x^2, y^2, z^2, (xy)^3, (yz)^3, [x, z]\rangle$.
> 6. $\langle x, y\mid x^ry=y^rx, x^n=1\rangle, r, n\in \Bbb N$.
> 7. $\langle x, y, z\mid [x, y]=x^t, [y,z]=y^t, [z,x]=z^t\rangle, t\in \Bbb Z$.

### Thoughts:

I think you just apply **Theorem 5**, but surely it can't be that simple.

> **Question 2 (optional):** Would someone do at least one of $1$-$7$ for me, please, just for illustration?

Also, it seems to me like `AbelianInvariants(G)` does the job in GAP since $G/G'\stackrel{?}{\cong}\operatorname{Abelianisation}(G)$, but I would prefer a more theoretical understanding of what's going on than just that.

Please help :)

Comment: Wow...It may well be not many will read aaaaaaaall that. Could you try to ask something *specific*...and, perhaps, ask two or more different questions?

Comment: The answer is that you transform the matrix of the group relators into Smith Normal Form, and then you can read off the invariant factors. This is the method used by GAP. It is a standard method, so I am not going to attempt to explain it here. You can probably find other MSE posts discussing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please fix Definition 1: "generator $x_i$ appears in the relator $r_i$" one of the subscripts should be $j.$
From the context the author is saying that $\overline R$ is the normal subgroup of $F$ generated by $R$.

The answer to your question is: Yes, just apply Theorem 5. It is that simple.

7) The relation matrix is $$
    \begin{matrix}
    t & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & t & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & t \\
    \end{matrix}
$$ so the group is $C_{|t|} \times C_{|t|} \times C_{|t|}$ for $|t|>1$. I'll leave the other cases, $|t|<2$, for you.

Comment: But it should be pointed out that the formulas in Theorem 5 for the the invariant factors in terms of $\gcd$s of minors of the matrix is not a practical method of computing them.

Comment: @DerekHolt You are absolutely right, Theorem 5 is unworkable. I looked up the Smith normal form, that you suggested, on Wikipedia. The algorithm looks much more doable. So far, however, I have been able to answer the questions just by doing group calculations using the relators and commutativity. That may be equivalent to the Smith form algorithm.